# Is it better to have 1 washer room in an apartment with 20 washers or 10 floors with 2 washers each in a dorm?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

The housing department of the university I study at gave a presentation on a new dorm being constructed slated for 2022. Being in the preliminary phases, they are currently designing how this building will look and one of the many questions they posed to our team concerned washing machines. They want to know what is better, a community washer room with 20 washers or a small washing room on each of the 10 residential halls with 2 washers each. (When I say washer I mean a washer and a dryer).

There are many factors in play here but I do think there can be a statistical answer to this question as opposed to relying solely on opinion and experience so I was eager to tackle this question using some of the techniques I am learning in my MS program. But I don’t know where to even begin and I wanted to pick your brain about the question. What do you think might be some assumptions that need to be made to answer this question? Even giving some narrow minded results helps i.e. Given a 10 hour window, which method has a higher probability of there being an open washer or given that going from the 2nd floor to the 10th floor is not a factor, etc. With these assumptions in place, how would you recommend tackling the question statistically (examples would be extremely helpful)?

If you have any ideas I would love to hear your take!!

Comment: the trade-off is between needing to move clothes a shorter distance versus being able to handle very spiky washer usage patterns, but it's not possible to say which is better unless you have a quantitative objective which weighs both.